# How to modify the twitter4j code and rebuild a new jar?

Tags: twitter4j

When I was using Twitter4j streaming api, I always ended up with memory usage problem.
I searched the Internet and someone provided a method which requires modifying original code.
I don't know how to do it, so if anyone knows, please help me.
Detailed step will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you can build Twitter4J using Maven.
But in most cases, you don't need to build it by yourself.
My assumption is that the problem is that you're storing all coming tweets to memory.
Try storing them outside the heap such as file system or RDBMS.

Comment: it's great to see u here.I didn't store tweets to memory, I store them into mysql database. The server I use have memory limits, so when real time memory usage gets larger and larger, I have to stop the application. I am not sure the answer I find is fit to my problem. I just want to give it a try.

Comment: I think you are right. Because my logic is too slow than the streaming speed, so many tweets get stored in the main memory which caused the problem.

Comment: Hi, glad to see the author of the lib here! I asked a similar question, showing my business logic at reception of a tweet. Slightly more than just storing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673980/how-to-avoid-outofmemory-error-with-twitter4j-streaming-api. Would love to have your views on that!