# How to avoid OutOfMemory error with Twitter4J streaming API?

Tags: java, mongodb, out-of-memory, twitter4j

After a couple of thousand tweets my app collecting tweets from the stream API with Twitter4J gets an OutOfMemory error.

At reception of a status, my code does:
- convert the status into a `TwitterStatus` object of my own. The reason is that the `Status` returned by Twitter4J is an interface, which can't be serialized in MongoDB.
- add this status to a list.
- if the size of the list is above 25 or 100 (depending on the speed of reception of tweets), save to db.

So it is all pretty simple, I don't store anything locally and yet I get this OutOfMemory error. Any clue how I could keep my memory footprint low?

The code:

```
StatusListener listener;
        listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                nbTweets++;
                    //the Status returned by Twitter4j is an interface, not serializable. I convert it into my own TwitterStatus object: same fields, serializable.
                    twitterStatus = convertStatus.convertOneToTwitterStatus(status);
                    twitterStatus.setJobId(jobUUID);
                    twitterStatuses.add(twitterStatus);

                    statusesIds.add(status.getId());
                    timeSinceLastStatus = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeLastStatus;

                    //**************************************
                    //adjusting the frequency of saves to DB, function of number of statuses received per second
                    if (timeSinceLastStatus < 200) {
                        sizeBatch = 100;
                    } else {
                        sizeBatch = 25;
                    }
                    timeLastStatus = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    progressLong = (Long) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startDateTime.getMillis()) * 100 / (stopTime - startDateTime.getMillis()));

                    if (statusesIds.size() > sizeBatch || progressLong.intValue() > progress) {

                        //**************************************
                        //saving statuses to the db.
                        dsTweets.save(twitterStatuses);
                        twitterStatuses = new ArrayList();

                        //**************************************
                        //updating list of status ids of the job.
                        opsJob = dsJobs.createUpdateOperations(Job.class).addAll("statuses", statusesIds, true);
                        dsJobs.update(updateQueryJob, opsJob);
                        statusesIds = new ArrayList();

                        //updating progress.
                        System.out.println("progress: " + progressLong);
                        progress = progressLong.intValue();
                        opsJobInfo = dsJobsInfo.createUpdateOperations(JobInfo.class).set("progress", progress).set("nbTweets", nbTweets);
                        dsJobsInfo.update(updateQueryJobInfo, opsJobInfo);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you know approximately how many tweets per second are you obtaining?

Comment: I filter the stream on the keyword "twitter", which is very frequent. I don't know exactly but about 10 tweets per second, I'd say. This generates lots of stall warnings, as well (but not relevant here?)

Comment: I don't know if this is the case but, in my experience, this error comes when the listener is obtaining more tweets than your application is able to process.

Comment: yes indeed. I am looking for a way to mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
Since v. 2.6, [MongoDB's default write concern is "acknowledge"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/), instead of unacknowledged. This slows down operations considerably.
Just adding `WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED` to all db writing operations solved the problem.